# React render-pdf open in new page onclick Slow issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

I created one table that has some features every single row can generate a pdf and download by using render-pdf npm, I want to show when the user clicks the download button pdf preview on a new page, it working but the issues rendering in the method they pass all data row data as props on page load it affects the page it's time sometimes, and page crashed I tried on single click send particular data in props it not working fine, Please Helps any Idea it very full for me.

Thanks for help

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Text, Page, Document, BlobProvider } from '@react-pdf/renderer';

const data = [
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'test',
    email: 'test@gmail.com'
  }
];

const MyDoc = ({ data }) => (
  <Document>
    <Page>
      <Text>{data.name}</Text>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Container>
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                <TableCell> Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Email</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Pdf</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {data.map(booking => (
                <TableRow key={booking.id}>
                  <TableCell>{booking.id}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{booking.name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{booking.email}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
        <BlobProvider document={<MyDoc BookingData={booking} />}>
          {({ url }) => (
            <a href={url} target="_blank">
              Open in new tab
            </a>
          )}
        </BlobProvider>
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where is the ```url``` property coming from?

Comment: URL will generate automatically form package based on our baseurl @AyushGupta

Comment: consider adding a codesandbox with a reproducible example. It would help everyone understand better and will get you a solution faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not completely sure but I think the problem lies here: `<BlobProvider document={<MyDoc BookingData={booking} />}>` and `const MyDoc = ({ data }) =>`. You have to destructure `BookingData` in `MyDoc` not `data`. I think the `data` in `MyDoc` is conflicting with `data` array.

Try this and let me know if it worked:

Change

```
const MyDoc = ({ data }) => (
  <Document>
    <Page>
      <Text>{data.name}</Text>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);
```

to

```
const MyDoc = ({ pageData }) => (
  <Document>
    <Page>
      <Text>{pageData.name}</Text>
    </Page>
  </Document>
);
```

And

```
<BlobProvider document={<MyDoc BookingData={booking} />}>
```

to

```
<BlobProvider document={<MyDoc pageData={booking} />}>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it not working @AyushGupta

Comment: No, it's taken some time to load the data  @AyushGupta

Comment: @Gokulram What do you mean when you say "taken some time"?

Comment: Because, in my original file have 20 data, after the page load when I move the cursor it should not show a cursor point, it's taken time after then only show cursor point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235864/discussion-between-gokulram-and-ayush-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

You pass to `const MyDoc = ({ data }) =>`  an array of object but when you call the MyDoc you pass an object of booking`document={<MyDoc BookingData={booking} />` try to fix this issue.
Intead of passing an array of object pass only the first element and let us know if this fix your issue